# What's a better way to chain data processing steps when the input from one is the output of the previous?

Tags: javascript, fetch, moodle

Basically, the script needs to fetch course and participant (students + instructors) information from the server, then redistribute the participants based on new grouping request.

It started out like this:

```
fetch(fetchAddress)
    .then (function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        appendCoursesData(data);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    })

getRelevantCourses();
getEnrolledUsers(siteAddress, token);
```

`getRelevantCourses()` needs the data from the fetch step and `getEnrolledUsers()` needs the data from the `getRelevantCourses()` step.

I soon realized that it wouldn't work because JavaScript doesn't exactly process things line by line. So, it expanded into this:

```
fetch(fetchAddress)
    .then (function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        appendCoursesData(data);
    })
    .then(function () {
        getRelevantCourses();
    })
    .then(function () {
        getEnrolledUsers(siteAddress, token);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

Then, inside `getEnrolledUsers()`, I ended up needing something like this:

```
fetch(fetchAddress)
    .then (function (response) {
        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (data) {
        appendUserData(data, courseName);
    })
    .then(function () {
        distributeParticipants();
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    })
```

Now, the logic is practically all messed up.

Wait times are no good. I have also tried `async/wait`, but it also didn't work right. (Although, it is very possible it just didn't work right because I wrote it all wrong.)

Here's what this is doing:

- the first `fetch` gets courses data from the server
- `appendCoursesData()` drops all the data from the fetch into an array
- `getRelevantCourses()` takes the course info from the previous array for all the courses needed by the user
- `getEnrolledUsers()` fetches the information of the users enrolled in the relevant courses
- `appendUserData()` selects relevant user data in the enrolled users list. Each line in the full list has more information than needed, so this function extracts just the needed parts of the data.
- `distributeParticipants()` regroups the users into smaller groups which is the overall goal of the script

What's a better way to do this?

Additional info: I am working with Moodle's Web Service API.

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you wrap each function in its own `.then()`? Isn't it just `fetch(...); appendCoursesData(...); getRelevantCourses(); getEnrolledUsers(...);`

Comment: Have a look at `async`/`await`

Comment: Regardless, if this code is laggy its probably at the servers end or in the `appendUserData` or `distributeParticipants` function. Not seeing it in this [mcve]

Comment: @Andreas I wrapped them so that they will wait for the previous line to finish. When they were outside the fetch, they were running on their own, so they didn't have data, so nothing worked. Chaining them inside the fetch worked until it didn't. I have tried the async/wait route, but it didn't work. Of course, I could have just misused it. (I should add that to the original post.)

Comment: For an actual answer you have to add the functions you're using - at least explain what they do and what they return (a `Promise`?) -> [mcve]

Comment: @Andreas Alright, I've added more descriptions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the three sequential functions are server calls as well, and the transit time is what is taking up most of the calculation, the best thing to do is define a custom endpoint which combines all the calculations into one.

The processing will still need to be sequential, but will all be performed on the server with one http call rather than three. Something like:

```
fetch(customCombinedFetchEndpointUrl).then(function(response){
    var json_response=response.json();
    var courses= json_response.courses
    var users= json_response.users
})
```

On the server it performs the processing of the functions and returns it at once. Here is some pseudo server code:

```
route("/customCombinedFetchEndpointUrl", inputs){
    course_data=getRelevantCoursesServer(inputs);
    user_data=getEnrolledUsersServer(course_data);
    return {course_data,user_data}
}
```

Comment: I can't see how it will be possible to combine the URL's. To be able to fetch the user data, you need the course ID's which are collected in the first fetch. Also, I cannot write in server-side code because access. Plus, we are specifically to work off Moodle's API's. I should add that in the original post.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try to use async/await

```
async function a(){
    return 1
}

async function b(value1){
    return value1+2
}

const value1= await a()
const result= await b(value1)
```

Comment: That's a terrible example to show how `async`/`await` works. And imho not really an answer for this question.

Comment: @Andreas the idea wasn't to explain how async/await works!! the purpose of the example was to show a better way to handle multiple promises instead of all the nested `.then`

Comment: Your example works perfectly without `async`/`await` - How does this show anything about `async`/`await` and how this would work with OPs script?

Comment: Yeah, i know it works without async/await, i am not returning any promise so there's no reason to await for the function, but as I said before it's an example not a solution/implementation